# Mutual Auth and other protocols

Tags: tls, authentication

I’ve implemented mutual TLS for web applications. But can you do mutual tls, specifically for auth for other protocols and services?

Services like

- RDP (windows client)
- SSH
- MySQL Workbench
- oracle studio
- etc

Is it true that you could do mutual auth for all these protocols?

Comment: `Is it true that you could do mutual auth for all these protocols?` -- no, it is not true.

Answer (score 1):

> ... etc

There is no generic "mutual auth" scheme available for arbitrary protocols the same as there is no generic "auth" scheme in the first place. What is possible depends on the specific protocol used. Protocols using TLS could do it in theory but there might be restrictions in actual specification or implementation on how TLS is used within the protocol. Protocols not using TLS might offer mutual auth too (like SSH does) but again it depends on the specifics of the protocol.